# Fixed positioning element within a container

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the "Recent Activity" div fixed within the "Recent-Activity-Grid" div, so that when you scroll through the overflown information "Recent Activity" stays in the same spot. How would I do that? http://jsfiddle.net/aJHnV/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how can you prevent "Recent Activity" div from scrolling as long as it is in the same div as the overflow content.  I had put the overflow content into a new div, and have that div scroll itself to make it work:
http://jsfiddle.net/aJHnV/12/

And as the other answer said position:fixed won't work because it is relative to the Viewport.

Answer (score 1):

A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport, or the browser window itself. So, you can't do this using only css.

Answer (score 1):

have a fixed position: i.e

```
.fixedGrid
{
    position: fixed;
}
```

Tell me if that worked. I have implemented this technique on my website. :)

Comment: huh? Can you show me a link because I have the same question.